# How can I get the pixel of the covered window?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows XP and studying C++. 
I am curious about the getting pixel from desktop.
Can I get the screen pixel with `GetPixel` function in the case that the window is covered with another window?  In the status of my window being covered, I was trying to call the `GetPixel`:

```
GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
```

But this call dosen't retrieve the pixel of the original window but the covering window or other color one.

How can I get the pixel of the covered window?

I add my code as the following ...

```
VOID GetDisplay(HWND& hwnd, RECT& area, COLORREF (*display)[1000]) {
    HDC hdc=GetDC(hwnd);
    for(INT x=area.left;x<=area.right;x++) {
        for(int y=area.top;y<=area.bottom;y++) {
            display[x][y]=GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
        }
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}


...

SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 300, 300, 500, 350, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
//EnableWindow(hwnd, TRUE);
SetFocus(hwnd);


GetDisplay(hwnd, within_wall, display);//trouble
```

The problem is causing on the GetPixel in GetDisplay.  GetPixel is returning the pixel color of the covering window.

Comment: You can just focus yours window first :)

Comment: I did so but couldn't get the result.

Comment: SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 300, 300, 500, 350, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
     //SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
     //EnableWindow(hwnd, TRUE);
     SetFocus(hwnd);

Comment: Please add this code to your original post. It's strange, i think SetFocus + GetPixel should do the job. Looks like we need to go deeper...

Comment: VOID GetDisplay(HWND& hwnd, RECT& area, COLORREF (*display)[1000]) {
  HDC hdc=GetDC(hwnd);
  for(INT x=area.left;x<=area.right;x++) {
   for(int y=area.top;y<=area.bottom;y++) {
    display[x][y]=GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
   }
  }
  ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
 }


 ...

 SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 300, 300, 500, 350, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
 SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
 SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
 //EnableWindow(hwnd, TRUE);
 SetFocus(hwnd);
 

 GetDisplay(hwnd, within_wall, display);//trouble

Answer (score 0):

There's no 100% way to do it, as windows are not required to, and generally don't, draw obscured areas. You will not be able to make the desktop a foreground window of course. And focus has no effect on visibility, as someone has mentioned `SetFocus`. That would be ineffective.

I have seen proposals to use `WM_PRINT` to access obscured pixels. Again this is not guaranteed, but the desktop window is pretty specific so if you get that to work, I guess it'll be somewhat reliable.

For more on this, see: [`PrintWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869(VS.85).aspx).

For what it's worth, `GetPixel` is extremely slow. You'll probably notice a performance problem in your code. You'll get much better performance by using methods like [`GetDIBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: PrintWindow is output the result of screen pixel.  I wanna read the result of screen pixel into variables or hdc or array.  I made the screen pixels  read into the memory device context and the result pixel color of memory dc into array.  But the result of array is black each elements